# Can `window.onload` be made fault-tolerant? Is there a better alternative?

Tags: javascript, onload

I am creating a webpage with multiple [GeoGebra files embedded in it](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Apps_Embedding). That means I have, for each GeoGebra applet, a `<div>` element in the `<body>` with an associated script to configure it; and at the end of the `<body>` I have the following script that adds all the applets to their associated `<div>`s:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        applet_0.inject('ggb-element-0');
        applet_1.inject('ggb-element-1');
        applet_2_NoLimit.inject('ggb-element-2-NoLimit');
        applet_2_YesLimit.inject('ggb-element-2-YesLimit');
        applet_3.inject('ggb-element-3');
        applet_4_Flat.inject('ggb-element-4-Flat');
        applet_4_Faster.inject('ggb-element-4-Faster');
    };
</script>
```

I noticed that if any of the first six lines of the script fails, for example if the associated file cannot be loaded, all lines following the failed line are not executed.

I want to make this work even if something goes wrong for one of the embeddings. I already discovered that I can't have multiple `window.onload` commands (only the last one is executed). Is there an alternative way to make this more fault-tolerant?

Comment: This is a normal JavaScript behavior.

Comment: Wrap each line in a `try {} catch {}` maybe?

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Multiple load event handlers**

You can have multiple load event listeners by calling [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) instead of setting `window.onload`. Listeners added in this way are executed in the order they are added. By providing `{once: true}` as the third argument the event listener will be removed automatically after being called. The listeners can be added anywhere in code before the load event has been fired that you deem appropriate.

For example the first two listeners could be added by

```js
addEventListener('load', ()=> applet_0.inject('ggb-element-0'), {once: true});

 //...

addEventListener('load', ()=> applet_2_NoLimit.inject('ggb-element-2-NoLimit'), {once: true});

// etc...
```

---

**Single `load` event handler**

Alternatively if you want to use a single load event handler, say to report errors in a consistent fashion, you could refactor the code to supply applet and string arguments to a single function that does the injection within a `try/catch` construct, as for example:

```js
addEventListener( "load", event => {
    [
      [ applet_0, 'ggb-element-0'],
      [ applet_1, 'ggb-element-1'],
      [ applet_2_NoLimit, 'ggb-element-2-NoLimit'],
      [ applet_2_YesLimit, 'ggb-element-2-YesLimit'],
      [ applet_3, 'ggb-element-3'],
      [ applet_4_Flat, 'ggb-element-4-Flat'],
      [ applet_4_Faster, 'ggb-element-4-Faster'],
    ]
    .forEach( args=> {
      const [applet, selector] = args;
      try {
        applet.inject(selector);
      }
      catch(err) {
        console.log(`injection of ${selector} into applet failed:`, err);
      }
    })
  },
  {once: true}
);
```

If you are unfamiliar with the `const [applet, selector] = args;` syntax please see [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax) on MDN.

Comment: Is `once: true` that useful? The `load` event fires only once anyway

Comment: @Bergi true, and the note under [window load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) reassures us that no other "load" events bubble up to window . AFAIK  `{once: true}` allows the handler to be garbage collected after being called, and if not a huge overhead could be safely omitted.

Comment: I implemented this on my webpage and tested it by purposefully breaking some of the import links, and it worked as desired. Thank you for your help!